# If OS is 64 bit

Tags: batch-file, command-line, vbscript

I am trying to write to a file, and I have an if statement to detect if user is using 64 or 32 bit of Operating System. I have tried this,

**write.bat**
(it makes a vbs file in appdata folder)

```
if defined ProgramFiles(x86) (
color 2
) else (
color 3
)
```

Which works perfectly. However, when it comes to write a file, it strangely tries to write both!

```
if defined ProgramFiles(x86) (

find "lnk.targetpath = ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""" %APPDATA%\System.vbs || echo lnk.targetpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe">>%APPDATA%\System.vbs

    ) else (

find "lnk.targetpath = ""C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe""" %APPDATA%\System.vbs || echo lnk.targetpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe">>%APPDATA%\System.vbs

    )
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: You have a wrong value in the `echo` part of the `else` clause. You are echoing the same value in the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this vbscript to check if user is using 64 or 32 bit of Operating System.

```
'un vbscript qui détermine automatiquement le type de votre système d'exploitation
Copyright = " © Hackoo © 2014"
MsgFr = "Le type de votre système d'exploitation " 
MsgAr = ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1608)&ChrW(1593)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1606)&ChrW(1592)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1605)&ChrW(32)&_
ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(1578)&ChrW(1588)&ChrW(1594)&ChrW(1610)&ChrW(1604)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1604)&_
ChrW(1582)&ChrW(1575)&ChrW(1589)&ChrW(32)&ChrW(1576)&ChrW(1603)
If Is64Bit = False then
    MsgBox MsgFr & MsgAr & VbCrLF & "32 bits" ,Vbinformation,MsgFr & MsgAr & Copyright
else
    Msgbox MsgFr & MsgAr & VbCrLF & "64 bits",Vbinformation,MsgFr & MsgAr & Copyright
End if
'**************************************************************************************************************
Function Is64Bit() 
    Is64Bit = False 
    Dim colOS : Set colOS = GetObject("WinMGMTS://").ExecQuery("SELECT AddressWidth FROM Win32_Processor",, 48) 
    Dim objOS 
    For Each objOS In colOS 
        If objOS.AddressWidth = 64 Then Is64Bit = True 
    Next 
End Function
'***************************************************************************************************************
```

In Batch you can give a try like this :

```
@echo off
wmic cpu get addresswidth | find "32" >nul  && echo systeme 32 bit || echo systeme 64 bit
pause
```